# Read comma separated values and insert in SQL Server 2016 table using String_Split

Tags: sql, csv, sql-server, stored-procedure

I know that this question has been asked many times over many years and I have read every one of them but I wanted to get a modern solution since software has changed and `String_Split` has been introduced in SQL Server 2016.

I have a stored procedure that splits a comma-separated string and inserts the values into a table after it deletes the value if it is already there. The code works but sometimes I write code that is totally convoluted.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Admin_Save_PMIDS]
    @MemberID INT,
    @PMIDList VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS PMID
    INTO #pmids
    FROM   
        (SELECT    
             CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(@PMIDList, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String) AS A
    CROSS APPLY 
        String.nodes('/M') AS Split (a)   

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[PublicationTable]
    WHERE (MemberID = @MemberID) 
     AND  PMID IN (SELECT PMID FROM #pmids)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PublicationTable] (PersonID, PMID, MemberID)
        SELECT        
            @MemberID, PMID, @MemberID
        FROM            
            [#pmids]
        WHERE        
            (LEN(PMID) > 0)

    DROP TABLE #pmids
END
```

As you can see I'm creating a temporary table and using an XML structure as a cross apply. The code works but since I'm doing a lot of updating in the application I figured I'd get some current opinions.

Answer (score 1):

The following are a few suggestions on how I'd write the stored procedure.

**Source Control**

If you don't already have a [database project](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-data-tools/hh272677(v=vs.103)), create one in [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/). Then check it in to source control. [Microsoft Azure DevOps Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/devops/) is free & private for teams of 5 or less (this is per project, so 5 developers per project). Then you'll be able to track changes you make to your stored procedures, views, tables, etc.

**Error Handling**

Use [Try, Catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) blocks to handle your errors. You can then write them to a log file or table.

**Tranactions**

Use [transactions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for rolling back your queries during testing. If a transaction is successful, all of the data modifications made during the transaction are committed and become a permanent part of the database. If a transaction encounters errors and must be cancelled or rolled back, then all of the data modifications are erased.

**Common Table Expressions (CTE)**

[CTE's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in your SQL help with documentation. The expression name can then let other developers know why you used that expression e.g. `current_suppliers` or `active_projects`.

**Merge**

If I need to perform more than one DML query on a table, I usually will use a [MERGE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement.

**Formatting**

I would download the following tool for SSMS and Visual Studio, [Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TaoKlerks.PoorMansT-SqlFormatterSSMSVSExtension) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter). I use it when I have to edit other developer's code. It's a great way to standardize your SQL. I find it does most of the formatting for me, but I'll still make a few changes after.

Here are the settings I used:

[image: screenshot]

**Commas**

I would put the commas in front to clearly define new columns. Versus code wrapped in multiple lines. It also makes trouble-shooting code easier.

e.g. `, S.[PersonID]`

**Estimated Execution Plan**

It's a good idea to check the [Estimated Execution Plan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017). The shortcut in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. You can even run 2 queries in the same tab to compare the plans. Then you can see differences in the query plans using [STRING_SPLIT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

---

**Revised SQL**

Without table definitions and sample records I was unable to test this, but it should give you a good start.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Admin_Save_PMIDS] 
      @MemberID INT
    , @PMIDList VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        SET XACT_ABORT ON;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

            WITH
            pm_ids
            AS
            (
                SELECT 
                      [PMID] = Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
                    , [PersonID] = @MemberID
                    , [MemberID] = @MemberID
                FROM 
                    (
                    SELECT CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(@PMIDList, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String
                    ) AS A
                CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)
            )
            MERGE [dbo].[PublicationTable] AS T
            USING pm_ids AS S
            ON T.[PMID] = S.[PMID] AND T.[MemberID] = S.[MemberID] --< Update the join to the correct unique key for the table
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
            THEN INSERT
            (
                  [PMID]
                , [PersonID]
                , [MemberID]
            )
            VALUES
            (
                  S.[PMID]
                , S.[PersonID]
                , S.[MemberID]
            )
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE --< You may want to add a WHERE clause here
            THEN DELETE
            --OUTPUT @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName], DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName], $action, inserted.*, deleted.* --< show the changed records here
            ;

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; --< use the rollback for testing
        --COMMIT TRANSACTION; --< use the commit for production

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --you can write this to a log table 
        SELECT 
              [ServerName] = @@SERVERNAME
            , [DatabaseName] = DB_NAME()
            , [ErrorProcedure] = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
            , [ErrorNumber] = ERROR_NUMBER()
            , [ErrorSeverity] = ERROR_SEVERITY()
            , [ErrorState] = ERROR_STATE()
            , [ErrorLine] = ERROR_LINE()
            , [ErrorMessage] = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            , [ErrorDateTime] = GETDATE();

        -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.  
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
        BEGIN  
            PRINT  
                N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' + 'Rolling back transaction.';
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
        END;  

        -- Test whether the transaction is committable.  
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
        BEGIN  
            PRINT  
                N'The transaction is committable.' + 'Committing transaction.';
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
        END;  

    END CATCH

END
```